# Purpose of 2 resistors in high pass filter?

Tags: filter, circuit-analysis

In the picture below, what is the purpose of R1? Compared to a high pass filter with 1 resistor, how does this affect Fc?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is basically a voltage divider between \$R_2\$ and \$R_1, C_1\$ in series, so the transfer function is the following: $${V_{out} \over V_{in}}={R_2 \over{R_2+R_1+{1\over j\omega C_1}}}={j\omega R_2C_1 \over 1+j\omega C_1(R_1+R_2)}$$

The first resistor limits the current into the capacitor, therefore it can charge slower, with a time constant of \$\tau=(R_1+R_2)C_1\$.

The cutoff frequency is smaller than without \$R_1\$: instead of $$f_c={1\over 2\pi R_2C_1}$$ it is $$f_c={1\over 2\pi(R_1+R_2)C_1}$$

Comment: I gotta learn how to write equations for Stackexchange.  That's a nice answer.

Comment: @AlanCampbell It's LaTeX. You can learn it from online tutorials and references or you can click the "edit" button on a question or answer with equations to see how the equations were typed in.

Answer (score 6):

Your voltage source is an "ideal" source. In practice, voltage sources vary, depending on how much current they need to source. This is modelled with an external series resistor - \$R1\$ in your diagram.
When you draw a lot of current, the the output voltage will drop by \$V = IR\$.
If \$R_2\$ is more than \$10 \times R_1\$, you can generally ignore \$R_1\$ for ballpark measurements. However, since \$R_2\$ and \$C\$ form a high pass filter, changing your selection for \$R_2\$ affects your value for \$C\$.

Comment: This answers a slightly different (equally relevant) question than hryghr's answer, but it's also a very good point.

Answer (score 4):

> Purpose of 2 resistors in high pass filter?

This is a (1st order) high-pass *attenuator*.  That is to say, the high-frequency asymptotic gain is less than one (unity).

An ordinary RC high-pass filter has a high-frequency gain that approaches unity.  What if, instead, one desires that the high-frequency voltage gain be *less* than unity?

One approach would be to use the circuit in your question.  At high enough frequencies, where the impedance of the capacitor is insignificant, the voltage gain is approximately

$$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} \approx \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} < 1$$

Of course, one must take into account the resistance of \$R_1\$ in the calculation of the corner frequency:

$$\omega_c = \frac{1}{(R_1 + R_2)C}$$

Note that, for a consistency check, as \$R_1 \rightarrow 0\$, we recover the equations for the ordinary RC high-pass filter.

In summary, this high-pass filter circuit gives an additional degree of freedom:  the high-frequency attenuation can be now be specified as a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show another method without math:

In high frequency, the C is shorted, so the transfer function should have "high frequency" gain

$$
\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}}
$$

So, the high frequency gain now won't be 1, and will be smaller, dependents on the ratio of \$\frac{R_{1}}{R_{2}}\$.

The circuit's time constant basically is
$$
\tau = R_{total} \times C_{1}=(R_{1}+R{2}) \times C_{1}
$$

And the well known first-order high-pass filter's transfer function is

$$
H(s)=\frac{1}{1+1/(s\tau)}
$$

Combine the high frequency gain and substitute the \$\tau\$, we get the whole

$$
H(s)=\frac{R_{2}}{R_{1}+R_{2}} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{s(R_{1}+R{2})C_{1}}}
$$